# Attempting a search button in gridview from access database in asp.net not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to make a search button for this database. I am unsure what I am doing wrong here. The error it gives me is  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This is in regards to the string constring.. etc. That is where it highlights it in red, anyways.

So, I read an article on access string connections. I did what it said. I am just not seeing what I am doing wrong.

The code:

```
public partial class StudentView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGrid();
}
private void BindGrid()
{
    string path = "C:\\Users\\Andrew James Heid\\Desktop\\12\\App_Code\\University       DB.accdb";

    string conString =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path].ConnectionString;

    string query = "SELECT * FROM Students";
    string id = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        id = string.Format(" where ID = '{0}'", id);
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + id);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: `.ConnectionStrings` expects a Connection String name, or an index.

Comment: @Hanlet what is an example?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** You are trying to access the `ConnectionString` which does not exist or invalid.

**Solution :** `<ConnectionStrings>` are maintained by configuration files and you need to setup them first and then access it from the Program.

**Step 1:** You need to create the `ConnectionString` in your Configuration file.

your configuration file `web.config` should have the following :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Andrew James Heid\Desktop\12\App_Code\University DB.accdb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Step 2:** You need to access the above mentioned `ConnectionString` from your Program either by using it's index or by it name as below:

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
```

OR

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: @AndrewHeid: did you add your connection string in your web.config file?

Comment: Where does that go exactly in the web config file?

Comment: @AndrewHeid: do you have `<ConnectionString/>` tag in your web.config file?if you have that you need to replace that with above mentioned `<connectionstring>`

Comment: that is not in my web.config file. :/

Comment: @AndrewHeid: ok then under `<configuration>` tag you can copy paste the above mentioned connection string and see wether you are able to access it or not.